# How to customize error response in a Turbogears2 controller

Tags: python, turbogears2

I'm using Turbogears2 to develop a small web application. And in some of my "controllers", I would like to response the client a json object with error information inside instead of an html page follows the standard error page template, because the ajax client can read the error message and have it's own way to display it.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can achieve this. If it is only bound to some controller you can easily register a controller wrapper for them (using `tg.hooks.wrap_controller`) and return `JSON` instead of plain error when needed. Controller wrappers are documented on http://turbogears.readthedocs.org/en/latest/turbogears/hooks.html#controller-wrappers

Otherwise another options is to use a decorator on the controller function to catch the error. This is what is also done by `tgext.crud`when reporting json errors through the `catch_errors` custom decorator: https://github.com/TurboGears/tgext.crud/blob/master/tgext/crud/decorators.py#L114

The controller wrapper solution is usually more powerful as it can be applied also to third party controllers. Otherwise you can even hijack the `ErrorController` in `controllers/error.py` to return json using `json.dumps` (TurboGears returns the response as is when it's a string or a `tg.Response` instance).